# mstl for multiple-frequency time-series where the frequencies are unknown

Tags: time-series, multiple-seasonalities

I create 2 data, the 1st repeats in 5 terms, the 2nd repeats in 15 terms. Then they are summed up and converted to `ts` using default setting.

```
library(forecast)
x0=c(3, 5.8, 6, 6.2, 2)
x1=rep(x0,24)
x2=rep(c(1,5,8,10,10,20,20,22,20,20,10,10,8,5,1),8)
x3=x1+x2
x4=ts(x3,start=1901)
```

Trying to use `plot(stl(x4,s.window='periodic'))` but get the following error message:

```
Error in stl(x4, s.window = "periodic") : 
  series is not periodic or has less than two periods
```

Tyr mstl by `plot(mstl(x4))`, but it seems doesn't detect the seasonality and produces:
[image]

Try check frequency using `tsp(x4)` and `frequency(x4)`. Both give output=1.
But `findfrequency(x4)` give output=15.

It seems that the `stl` and `mstl` are working based on the `frequency=` setting in the `ts()` or the `seasonal.periods=` in `msts` itself, i.e. the frequencies are pre-determined when we create the `ts` or `msts`.

If I have a multiple-frequency time-series, but don't know what the frequencies are, I wish the function to detect them, and followed by doing a mstl-decomposition, how could this be done?